# JavafX - Dynamic ImageView Set Default Size

Tags: javafx, imageview, default, dynamic-resizing

I have an ImageView which I have configured so that it is resized to fit its parent AnchorPane with the two following lines of code (both the AnchorPane and the image are square).

```
preview.fitWidthProperty().bind(previewPane.maxWidthProperty());
preview.fitHeightProperty().bind(previewPane.maxWidthProperty());
```

I have also set a fitWidth of 450 px in an fxml file that injects all nodes. When I create an instance of this object however it opens the preview with a width equal to that of the loaded image (2000 px) and not 450 px. The resizing functionality works as expected and it is possible to shrink it down to 450 px. I was wondering however if it is possible to make sure it opens up with a default size different from that of the width of the image but also making sure so that it grows and shrinks with its parent.

I have tried setting loads of different default widths in both java code and fxml but the only thing that seems to work is unbinding the fitWidth which I don't want.

Do you have any suggestions as to how I might solve this?

> Main:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainTest extends Application {

    @FXML private AnchorPane previewPane;
    @FXML private ImageView preview;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Test.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        fxmlLoader.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }

        preview.fitWidthProperty().bind(previewPane.maxWidthProperty());
        preview.fitHeightProperty().bind(previewPane.maxWidthProperty());
        Scene scene = new Scene(previewPane);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

> FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="previewPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <ImageView fx:id="preview" fitHeight="450.0" fitWidth="450.0" layoutX="55.0" layoutY="36.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@Blue%20Eyes%20White%20Dragon.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**EDIT:** [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tmyjo5bPPdBS62eJ9VCZaRE3tDzUiplG) is a MCVE of my problem.

Comment: Seems like you need to make sure your `preview` node's width and height are set.

Comment: @Sedrick I'm Sorry, what do you mean? They are set in fxml but then bound as seen above.

Comment: I mean, set the `AnchorPane's`(`previewPane`) width and height. It seems to me that if you bound the height and width to a `Pane`, then setting that `Pane's` height and width should fix the problem.

Comment: @Sedrick that doesn't work unfortunately. It still opens up with a width of 2000 px.

Comment: Create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Sedrick Sorry about the delay (had some issues with Eclipse) but I have now added an MCVE.

Comment: Your structure is wrong.

Comment: @Sedrick did you delete your own answer? Also, what if I am not able to set the stage width? What if this component is included inside a SplitPane and should vary with the size of its container here?

Comment: Yes, I did. It was not correct. Now it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173407/discussion-between-ivar-eriksson-and-sedrick).

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your project is wrong. Also, to fix the problem you are having, you need to set the `Scene` size.

**Code to get the `ImageView` from the `Controller`**

```
//Code in the Main
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
FXMLDocumentController fXMLDocumentController = loader.getController();
ImageView preView = fXMLDocumentController.getPreview();

//Code in the Controller
public ImageView getPreview()
{
    return preview;
}
```

**Code to set the `Scene's` size**

```
stage.setWidth(450);
stage.setHeight(450);
```

> Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication213 extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        FXMLDocumentController fXMLDocumentController = loader.getController();
        ImageView preView = fXMLDocumentController.getPreview();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setWidth(450);
        stage.setHeight(450);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        preView.fitHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());
        preView.fitWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

> Controller

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable
{

    @FXML
    private ImageView preview;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
    {
        // TODO

    }

    public ImageView getPreview()
    {
        return preview;
    }
}
```

> FXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="previewPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication213.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <ImageView fx:id="preview" fitHeight="450.0" fitWidth="450.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <image>
                <Image url="@Blue%20Eyes%20White%20Dragon.png" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Finally, you need to uncheck `Preserve Ratio`. The `FXML` should already have this unchecked. I am pointing this out because it's important.

[image]

Comment: What if I am not able to set the scene width? What if this component is included inside a SplitPane and should vary with the size of its container here?

Comment: Each side of a `SplitPane` has a root node.  Like, for example, an `AnchorPane`. Bind your `ImageView` to the appropriate `Node`.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem and I can tell this is going to require a long explanation. I will open a chat if that is okay.